# Python Data Frame: Change Negative Polar Angles to Positive

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, polar-coordinates

This does not work:

```
df[df['angle'] < 0]] += 360
```

How do I solve this problem? I need to have an already existing pandas dataframe with negative and positive angles update to positive polar coordinate angles (0 to 360 degrees).

Have:

```
[-135, -90, -45, 180, 135, 90, 45, 0, etc... ] # polar 'angles' in degrees (with negatives)
```

Want:

```
[315, 270, 225, 180, 135, 90, 45, 0, etc... ] # polar 'angles' in degrees (positive only)
```

// Edit (for responses): /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

This line, `df[df['angle'] < 0]] += 360`, gives a type error:
"TypeError: Could not operate 360 with block values must be str, not float."

The information of the dataframe 'angle' is:
"Name: angle, dtype: in64,

The original 'brute force' solution I use is:

```
for i in range(len(df['angle'])):
    if df['angle'][i] < 0:
        df['angle'][i] += 360
```

This works, but it is slow, and gives a warning, which then tells me to look up documentation on dataframe indexing.

Comment: Explain 1st and 3rd results?

Comment: This does not work? `df[df.angle <0] += 360.`

Comment: It gives a type error. Please see edit in original post.

Comment: Try casting your column to int `df['angle'] = df['angle'].astype(int)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
df['angle'] %= 360
```

to convert all angles regardless of sign to the range `[0-360)`. This will work correctly for negative degrees or for angles whose absolute value exceeds 360

examples:

```
-270 % 360 == 90
-675 % 360 == 45
675 % 360 == 315
```

---

if you want to handle only negative degrees (i.e. allow 450 instead of converting it to 90):

```
df.iloc[df.angle < 360, 'angle'] %= 360
```